# What is the use of Head = Current = ptr; in (c)?

Tags: c

```
struct data *createNew(int digit)
{
struct data *ptr = (struct data*)malloc(sizeof(struct data));
if (ptr == NULL) {
    puts("Failure");
    return NULL;
}
ptr->number = digit;
ptr->Next = NULL;

Head = Current = ptr;
return ptr;
}
```

I do not yet fully understand structures. Can someone, please, elaborate what is the purpose of (Head = Current = ptr;)? I understand that it creates a head for the next structure, but I don't understand how.

Comment: Without a greater explanation of where you got this code and what this code is meant to be doing, I can't make head nor tail of it.  At the very least, it is leaking the previous Head, which seems like a bad idea.

Comment: @Kevin It's obviously a brilliant way of getting around the atrocious performance of linked lists by limiting them to a single element.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is not related to the structures, but to the way C evaluates expressions. You have `ptr`, which is a pointer to some memory location that stores a structure. Basically, is the address of a memory location (an integer value). Then, you have 2 pointers, Head and Current, which are global pointers to a structure of the same type as ptr, and you want to make them point to the same structure as ptr. Basically, what you want is to allocate memory for the new structure, which is referenced by ptr, and make Head and Current point to the same memory location. Thus, you want the following assignments:

```
Head = ptr;
Current = ptr;
```

You can contract those 2 expressions in one:

```
Head = Current = ptr;
```

, which is evaluated as:

```
(Head = (Current = ptr));
```

So, ptr is first assigned to Current, then the value of that assignment (which is ptr) is assigned to Head. And now you have a Head, which is the beginning of the linked list, and a Current pointer, which may be used for iteration and has an initial value equal to Head.